# php Fatal error: Class '' not found in..doesnt specify the class

Tags: php

I'm getting a `class not found` error but without the name of the class. I got the code from [here](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/)
but when I try to run it, it gives the following error..

```
Fatal error: Class '' not found in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs\framework\library\controller.class.php on line 16
```

and the following is the controller

```
<?php

class Controller {

    protected $_model;  
    protected $_controller;   
    protected $_action;  
    protected $_template;

    function __construct($model, $controller, $action) {

        $this->_controller = $controller;
        $this->_action = $action;
        $this->_model = $model;

        include 'model.class.php';//other similar posts suggested this but its not working
        $this->$model = new $model;
        $this->_template = new Template($controller,$action);

    }

    function set($name,$value) {
        $this->_template->set($name,$value);
    }

    function __destruct() {
        $this->_template->render();
    }

}
```

I'm assuming its the model class which is not being found. The model class code is

```
<?php  
class Model extends SQLQuery {  
    protected $_model;

  function __construct() {

        $this->connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
        $this->_model = get_class($this);
        $this->_table = strtolower($this->_model)."s";
    }

    function __destruct() {
    }
}
```

and sqlquery class is

```
<?php

class SQLQuery {  

    protected $_dbHandle;  
    protected $_result;

    /** Connects to database **/

    function connect($address, $account, $pwd, $name) {
        $this->_dbHandle = @mysql_connect($address, $account, $pwd);
        if ($this->_dbHandle != 0) {
            if (mysql_select_db($name, $this->_dbHandle)) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /** Disconnects from database **/

    function disconnect() {
        if (@mysql_close($this->_dbHandle) != 0) {
            return 1;
        }  else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    function selectAll() {
      $query = 'select * from `'.$this->_table.'`';
      return $this->query($query);
    }

    function select($id) {
      $query = 'select * from `'.$this->_table.'` where `id` = \''.mysql_real_escape_string($id).'\'';
      return $this->query($query, 1);    
    }


    /** Custom SQL Query **/

  function query($query, $singleResult = 0) {

    $this->_result = mysql_query($query, $this->_dbHandle);

    if (preg_match("/select/i",$query)) {
    $result = array();
    $table = array();
    $field = array();
    $tempResults = array();
    $numOfFields = mysql_num_fields($this->_result);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfFields; ++$i) {
        array_push($table,mysql_field_table($this->_result, $i));
        array_push($field,mysql_field_name($this->_result, $i));
    }


      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($this->_result)) {
        for ($i = 0;$i < $numOfFields; ++$i) {
          $table[$i] = trim(ucfirst($table[$i]),"s");
          $tempResults[$table[$i]][$field[$i]] = $row[$i];
        }
        if ($singleResult == 1) {
          mysql_free_result($this->_result);
          return $tempResults;
        }
        array_push($result,$tempResults);
      }
      mysql_free_result($this->_result);
      return($result);
    }


  }

    /** Get number of rows **/
    function getNumRows() {
        return mysql_num_rows($this->_result);
    }

    /** Free resources allocated by a query **/

    function freeResult() {
        mysql_free_result($this->_result);
    }

    /** Get error string **/

    function getError() {
        return mysql_error($this->_dbHandle);
    }
}
```

I'm new to PHP and I'm using PHP 5.5.15. I know I should probably switch this to pdo, but i just want to get this working before `gettin jiggy with it`.

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Where is `Controller` used?

Comment: Your `model.class.php` is probably not in the same directory as your `controller.class.php`. Try specifying an absolute path to it and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: There's no need to use bulletin board speak here. The error message itself clearly hints at `$model` being an empty string when passed to your "controller".

Comment: ^ yep, which would help if you provided code that shows calling the `Controller` class, such as `$something = new Controller('',,...)`.

Comment: And also put an error prevention into that function to make sure `$model` is set and not empty before trying to use it to instantiate an arbitrary class. You could even do a check to see if the class exists :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple said, you have this function for your controller:

```
function __construct($model, $controller, $action) {
    $this->$model = new $model;
}
```

You need to give a `$model`, wich would be the name of a class. You give no name. This is why class "" can not be found.

If we would write this:

```
$controller = new Controller("mycrazymodel", null, null);
```

It means:

```
function __construct($model, $controller, $action) {
    //$this->$model = new $model;
    $this->$model = new mycrazymodel; //above means this, if $model = "mycrazymodel"
}
```

So what does this mean for you?

Locate the call of the `Controller::__construct` method, which typical mean `new Controller(...)` and make sure, you give the classname as `$model` parameter.

Take a look at the manual for further information: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php